# Erro em comparar strings

Tags: java, string, comparação

Preciso fazer um programa que recebe uma frase, depois uma letra, e retorna quantas vezes a letra aparece na frase. Então fiz isso:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Exercicio1_string {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStreamReader c = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader cd = new BufferedReader(c);
        String frase = "";
        String letra = "";

        System.out.println("Escreva uma frase: ");
        try {
            frase = cd.readLine();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro de entrada");
        }

        System.out.println("Escreva uma letra para encontrar na frase: ");
        try {
            letra = cd.readLine();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro de entrada");
        }

        int contador = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++) {
            if(frase.charAt(i).equals(letra)) {
                contador++;
            }
        }

        if(contador == 0) {
            System.out.println("Nao existe a letra na frase");
        } else {
            System.out.println("A letra aparece " + contador + " vezes");
        }

    }
}
```

Porém estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Exercicio1_string.java:37: error: char cannot be dereferenced
>            if(frase.charAt(i).equals(letra)) {
> ```

Que faz referência a esse bloco de código:

```
        int contador = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++) {
            if(frase.charAt(i).equals(letra)) {
                contador++;
            }
        }
```

Gostaria de saber o motivo do erro e se as funções `charAt()` e  `equal()` estão sendo usadas corretamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A forma mais performática e idiomática seria o uso direto com `char` tanto na letra que quer buscar quanto no acesso individual. Isto se dá mais fácil com `o` for` que varre uma coleção de dados de forma automática. Se você ficar chamando um método em um laço terá um enorme desperdício de processamento.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Exercicio1_string {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStreamReader c = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader cd = new BufferedReader(c);
        String frase = "";
        char letra = ' ';
        System.out.println("Escreva uma frase: ");
        try {
            frase = cd.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro de entrada");
        }
        System.out.println("Escreva uma letra para encontrar na frase: ");
        try {
            letra = cd.readLine().charAt(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro de entrada");
        }
        int contador = 0;
        for (int caractere : frase.toCharArray()) if (caractere == letra) contador++;
        if (contador == 0) System.out.println("Nao existe a letra na frase");
        else System.out.println("A letra aparece " + contador + " vezes");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UecDae). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wqvvftkl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/CountChars.java).

Answer (score 1):

O método `charAt` retorna o tipo primitivo `char`, por isso não pode ser referenciado. Você pode substituir o trecho:

```
if(frase.charAt(i).equals(letra)) {
    contador++;
}
```

por:

```
if(frase.charAt(i) == letra.charAt(0)) {
    contador++;
}
```